# Split a large packed file based on hex/string

Tags: windows, notepad++, png

I have a large package file which has a lot of files in it.
For example, a file named "**Data.Rpack**" which has 50 ***.PNG** files.
When I opened a **PNG** image file with Notepad++, it started with "`‰PNG`"
And then I opened "**Data.Rpack**", and I found 50 "`‰PNG`" in it.

Like this:

```
‰PNG~~~%~~~~‰PNG~~~~$~~~‰PNG~~~~@~!~~‰PNG~~~5~~M~~ , etc
```

I want to split that large file into 50 files, where every single file starts with "`‰PNG`".

So it will be saved into multiple files, like this:

```
Data1.PNG
Data2.PNG
Data3.PNG
Data4.PNG
etc.
```

It looks like extracting files based on a string (or hex) with the same format.

*The file extension is not RPACK. I wrote it as an example of file type.*

The file I have is just an ordinary file package, a lot of files in there without any compression and not encrypted. In one file package, we could have some PNG, WAV, or DDS file in it, and I can split it manually using HxD, but sometimes one file package could contain hundreds of files, so it's hard to split it manually one by one.

Comment: Are you sure that all of `‰PNG` occurrences are distinct PNG files and not image data of a single or multiple PNG files?

Comment: No, in one package file has 1,603 PNG and I checked that.
Not just PNG, there are OGG audio files in there too, If I split them, the file will work perfectly like its original format.

Comment: Seems a format similar to **Zip**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the program
[csplit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html),
that can split on a string or regex pattern (among other options).

Csplit is available in Windows in WSL or other packages porting Linux apps.

Some such packages are
[CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm),
[Tiny Unix Tools for Windows](https://tinyapps.org/blog/201606040700_tiny_unix_tools_windows.html)
or
[Cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder).

Comment: The file extension is not *.rpack. I wrote it as an example of file type.

The file I have is just an ordinary file package, a lot of files in there without any compression and not encrypted. There is some PNG, WAV, or DDS file in it, I can split it manually using HxD, but sometimes in 1 file package could contain a hundreds of file, it's hard to split it manually one by one.

Comment: Which program was it packed with, do you know?

Comment: The file name is "assets.pfp" from Diner Dash games.
The game images data are packed on that file, I want to cut and save every single file (unpacking).

Comment: Try to use the program [csplit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/csplit.1.html) available in WSL or in products such as Cmder or CoreUtils for Windows.

Comment: I'm using Windows. Is that available for Windows? or app who is same as csplit?

Comment: It's available on Windows as part of packages porting Linux apps. Such as [CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), [Tiny Unix Tools for Windows](https://tinyapps.org/blog/201606040700_tiny_unix_tools_windows.html), Cmder.

Comment: Great! I have tried and it works. Thanks!